# Reporting betareg outcome - how to compare non-nested models?

Tags: r, anova, likelihood-ratio, model-comparison, beta-regression

I am looking for advice how to gain and report results using beta regression for an ANCOVA-like model.
My model is as follows:

```
Model <- betareg(plants ~ rain * cows)
```

The questions I want to answer is whether `rain`, `cows`, or interaction between these two factors have an influence to plant relative biomass (expressed as % in a range of (0;1)). If this was a GLM, I would use `anova(Model)` and report results from the likelihood ratio test using `Chisq`. Since ANOVA is not suitable for `betareg`, I read that I could use `lrtest` or wald test and compare it manually, like this:

```
 m1 <- betareg(plants~ 1 ,data = mydata)
 m2 <- betareg(plants~ cows,data = mydata)
 m3 <- betareg(plants~ rain ,data = mydata)
 m4 <- betareg(plants~ rain:cows,data = mydata)
 lrtest(m1,m2,m3,m4)
```

However, as I understand this is not correct, as my models are not fully nested (in particular m2 and m3). I am wondering if there is an alternative to compare these models and determine which factors could have significantly affected plant biomass?

P.S. This question is closely related to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183329/anova-like-object-for-betaregression however, the answer did not help in my case.

Comment: One potential option is to use `emmeans::joint_tests(Model)`.  The `emmeans` package supports `betareg` objects, but be sure to read up on the documentation for the `joint_tests` function.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Concerning the comparisons, maybe you are right and it could help to avoid using reference model (plants~1). However I find it harder to interpret, for instance if both cows and rain had significant additive effect (but maybe I am confusing something)

Comment: I'm deleting my previous comment.  It was confused.  I was trying to get to Achim Zeileis's answer, but I wrote it too quickly, with too little checking on the actual results.

Answer (score 2):

The situation is completely analogous to (generalized) linear models where you could do forward or backward selection via the so-called "encompassing" model (`cows + rain`) in your case to the interaction model. Only the two non-nested models with one main effect cannot be compared directly with a LR or Wald test but both can be compared against the encompassing model. Or you adopt an information criterion (AIC or BIC, ...) instead. So you could do

```
m0   <- betareg(plants ~ 1)
mC   <- betareg(plants ~ cows)
mR   <- betareg(plants ~ rain)
mCR  <- betareg(plants ~ cows + rain)
mCxR <- betareg(plates ~ cows * rain)
```

Then you can test both paths:

```
lrtest(m0, mC, mCR, mCxR)
lrtest(m0, mR, mCR, mCxR)
```

and use these to do either forward or backward selection. Or you could do:

```
BIC(m0, mC, mR, mCR, mCxR)
```

or something like that.

Further comments:

- I guess that `plants ~ cows * rain` and `plants ~ cows:rain` is really of interest to you.
- You might want to consider models where also the precision (phi) depends on cows and/or rain. Of course, this creates even more potential models to select from.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would it make sense then for testing the effect of cows to run `lrtest(m0,mC)`, for rain `lrtest(m0, mR)` and for the interaction `lrtest(mCR, mCxR)`? Just in this case I have another question. Here m0 is a reference model, I defined it as  `betareg(plants ~ 1)` as I saw it like that in several sources. But is there a reason to choose ~1? Basically, I would assume I would like to check if mC explains my data better than a random model.

Comment: If you want to do _test-based_ model selection, I would recommend to either use a forward selection (adding the most significant term in each step, if any) or backward selection (dropping the most non-significant term in each step, if any). Alternatively, you can do _information-criterion-based_ selection which is not stepwise. In models with so few terms, the strategies often (but not always) lead to the same results. As for `y ~ 1`: This means that all observations come from the same beta distribution without any effects of cows and/or rain.

Comment: My goal is not to select the model explaining my data best per se, but to test three hypothesis and provide statistical support for/against them: 1) Cows alone affect plant biomass, 2) Rain affects plant biomass, 3) There are interactive effects of cows and rain on plant biomass. I could of course select for a model explaining the data best, but I believe it is the results of the selection procedure what are of interest for me. So that I could report the results like e.g. "Plant biomass vary positively with amount of rain (Chisq=8.7, df=4, p<0.05)". Please correct me if this approach is wrong.